# Select last child except if it is also first child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have set up a rule for the last LI tag of my UL:

```
.className li:last-child {
  stuff: here;
}
```

Am I able to set a rule in the CSS that says "apply this style to the last LI tag EXCEPT if the `last-child` is also the `first-child`", i.e. there is only one LI tag in the OL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use it together with `:not()` selector.

> CSS pseudo-class [`:not(X)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) is a functional notation taking a simple selector *X* as an argument. It matches an element that is not represented by the argument.

```css
li:last-child:not(:first-child) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item a</li>
  <li>item b</li>
  <li>item c</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>only item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after. Perfect.

Answer (score 2):

You can leave your CSS as it is and add a rule that overwrites it if it is the first child:

```
/* What should happen in the last child */
.className li:last-child {
    stuff: here;
}

/* If there is only one child the previous one will be overwritten by this one */
.className li:first-child {
    /* default values */
}
```

Alternatively, you can use something more advanced:

```
/* Select the last child if it is not the first child */
li:last-child:not(:first-child) {
    stuff: here;
}
```

I would use the second, but that depends upon your familiarity with CSS.

**More analytically**:

- `:last-child` - Select the last child
- `:not()` - If it's not
- `:first-child` - The first child

Comment: The problem then is I'm having to set the style for the LIs again by defining the first-child.

Comment: Not using `:not` was also my first attempt, but for reasons I do not know that solution does not work in Chrome 103.0.5060.114 on Windows 7. Even if I add `!important` to the :first-child rule, the `:last-child` rule will overwrite it. Seems to be a bug. The `:not` solution however works and is also more self-documenting in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

There is an `:only-child` selector:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/o/only-child/

As well as an `:only-of-type` selector

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/o/only-of-type/

You could use these to overwrite anything the `:last-child` selector is modifying.

Comment: Only thing is I don't want to have to set another style if it's an only-child. I want to say "only apply this style if there's more than one LI in the UL."

Answer (score 1):

You can prepend `* +` before a compound selector like `li:last-child` to prevent it from selecting a first child:

```css
.className > * + li:last-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="className">
  <li>item a</li>
  <li>item b</li>
  <li>item c</li>
</ul>
<ul class="className">
  <li>only item</li>
</ul>
```